# Помогите с конфликтом скриптов

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Внизу страницы последовательно подгружаются

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

при этом последний `owl.carousel.min.js` ломает работу `bootstrap.js`(перестает всплывать окно) независимо от своего местоположения.

при этом в консоле появляется ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: this.$backdrop.one(...).emulateTransitionEnd is not a function`

Помогите решить проблему! Пациент: http://l90812x0.beget.tech/children/

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 1):

При возникновении ошибок подобного рода `Uncaught TypeError: this.$backdrop.one(...).emulateTransitionEnd is not a function` необходимо подключить скрипт из bootstrap-библиотеки
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ad379ffb4a0fde7416ae076e68141300fc583018/js/transition.js

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема. Что только ни пытался сделать: менял местами вызовы js в header и в footer, вставлял noConflict... Бесполезно. Все решилось простым переставлением местами блоков (с div) на странице :)

Comment: я был бы премного благодарен, если бы меня ткнули носом. что менять ума ни приложу